# How to Insert xml data into xml tag of xml file in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I would like to add xml data in xml tag of a file. 
This is my code snippet.

```
        Dim file As String = txtPath.Text
        Dim xDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
        xDoc.Load(file)

        Dim message11 As String = "Test"
        Dim root As String
        root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Name.ToString 
        Dim xmlNode As XmlNode
        xmlNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(root & "//BRAND/DESCRIPTION")


        xDoc.Save(file)
```

I would like to add data in xml tag of the file. the results should be like this:

```
<BRAND>
    <DESCRIPTION>Test</DESCRIPTION>
</BRAND>
```

I want to add data in specific xml tag in xml file. I have tried detected the xml tag in the file but I'm lost on how to insert the data to the specific element. Any idea? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the actual question here? What is the issue? What are you actually getting that differs from what you want to get?

Comment: How can I add the data in xml tag as shown above? @freefaller

Comment: `xmlNode.Value = message11` ?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.value?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlNode_Value

Comment: it displays an error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll. Additional information: Cannot set a value on node type 'Element'.` @MarkL

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is closer to your needs?

```
    Dim xDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
    xDoc.LoadXml("<BRAND><DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION></BRAND>")
    Dim xmlNode As XmlNode
    xmlNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/BRAND/DESCRIPTION")
    xmlNode.InnerText = "test"
```

Result: `"<BRAND><DESCRIPTION>test</DESCRIPTION></BRAND>"`

Comment: What `"<BRAND><DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION></BRAND>"` in  xDoc.LoadXml is for?

Comment: That's just for the example code - you didn't provide more than the sample xml (that is, you didn't show the contents of the file being loaded), this is a (potential) [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show resolution to your question. You'd want to be loading the actual file when you take this example, if it provides resolution, and implement your changes.